# I can't debug my program in C and i dont know what to do Visual Studio just recommend me add ";" between "=1","<9", "++"

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
#include <sdio.h>

int main(void)

for (int k = 1, k <19, k++); {
    printf("%d*%d=%d \n", k, k, k * k);
    return 0;
}
```

I have just started learn C and faced with that problem. If you can, recommend me good guide for beginner in addition. :)

Comment: 1. You need newline after proprocessing directive like `#include`. 2. `sdio.h` is not in the standard library. Probably you want to use `stdio.h` (`t` is inserted) 3. Separator for expressions in `for` statement is not `,` but `;` 4. The semicolon after `for ( ... )` will separate the block after that from the `for` statement and will prevent your code from doing what you expect.

Comment: Format your code properly please.

Comment: Also you have to surround the function body by `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
for (int k = 1, k <19, k++);
```

In a for statement, you should separate elements with a semicolon (`;`)

```
for (int k = 1; k <19; k++)
```

There's also no (`;`) at the end of it.

Also, you should include `<stdio.h>` instead of `<sdio.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains multiple syntax errors and multiple logical errors. And the original version was so poorly formatted that is was practically unreadable by a human.

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  for (int k = 1; k < 19; k++)
  {
    printf("%d*%d=%d \n", k, k, k * k);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Your original code reformatted and with comments:

```
#include <sdio.h>

int main(void)
// { missing here
for (int k = 1, k <19, k++); {   // the final ; should not be here
           // ^      ^ use ; instead of ,
    printf("%d*%d=%d \n", k, k, k * k);
    return 0;  // should not be in the loop but after the loop
}
// } missing here
```